# ASP.NET Passing Inconsistent DateTime Format to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, datetime

I know this is an age-old question but I'm not exactly new to it and I haven't found an answer which helps me so far!

I've got an ASP.NET site which displays data from an SQL Server 2005 database.  At the top of the page are 'Date From' and 'Date To' textboxes which are used to filter the data shown beneath.

The data is displayed using an SqlDataSource, and the two dates are passed as parameters to a Stored Procedure.  The textboxes display the dates and accept input in UK date format (dd/MM/yyyy) and it works fine.

Now I've added a new page with exactly the same setup, displaying slightly different data. In the backend I created a new Stored Procedure by copying and pasting my original one, it's almost identical.  And yet on this page I get errors with my dates because they're being read as MM/dd/yyyy, meaning that today's date, for example, 15th August 2011, is passed as 15/08/2011 and isn't a valid date.

I've checked over everything and I can't understand why this should work on one page and not another, especially when I've basically just copied all of the original code and tweaked it slightly.  Can anyone suggest anything I can check that I might not have thought of?

Comment: The problem is definitely with the local report (RDLC). Even though my SQLDataSource works fine, and a GridView is happily populated with the data, filtered by the date parameters I'm passing to the Stored Procedure, the RDLC is taking it upon itself to check the date parameters, and it doesn't seem clever enough to work out that they're in a format other than what it's expecting.  This is so irritating - the report shouldn't care about the dates at all.  There are no dates on the report, no parameters at all, the dates are nothing to do with the report!  Filtering is done in the datasource.

Answer (score 2):

- The text boxes are strings, which are in the thread local which is set from the browser (langauges).
- Convert them to aa DateTime object first, using a local aware transformation, then write the dateTime object to the server. NEVER (!) deal with strings to sql server unless you format them in ISO independent form (2011-08-17 23:52:11).

But in general, ASp.NET will show dates, times, numbers in the local langauge of the browser. Either turn that off, or deal with it. It is nice for the user. So, check locales - user, server process. What is the thread current locale?

Comment: I might have just got closer to the cause of the problem.  On my page that works the data is displayed in a GridView.  On the page that doesn't it's in a report (RDLC).  So I added a GridView to the page that isn't working and that displayed the correct data.  So somehow the problem is with the report.  The report doesn't have any parameters or any date/time fields on it, it should just be displaying the data specified in the DataSource, which is correct because it shows the right data in a GridView!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQL convert in stored procedure like:

```
convert(varchar, @yourdateParameter, 103) for format dd/mm/yyyy
```

or

```
convert(varchar, @yourdateParameter, 101) for format mm/dd/yyyy
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've tried that, even though I didn't have to in the sp that's working, and it didn't make any difference.  As per my comment above, it seems that the correct data is being retrieved, it's just the report which is somehow trying to display different data than the datasource is returning.